# How smart is using a space as a character in a password

Tags: security, passwords

Would using a space be an uncommon character to use in a password. Uncommon enough to make it smart to use?

Or would by using a space, make it easier to crack?

Comment: Any expansion out of the normal character repertoire helps (a little).  Using spaces won't make it easier to crack.

Comment: This is covered on the IT Security site: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10872/1369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add white space as password. If you can't use ALT+0160
It will be working.
Even if you want to rename your folder with single white space you can use this formula.

If you getting help.Vote for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Microsoft recommend it so it must be good!

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tips-for-creating-a-strong-password